# Shell script for string with variable which store command output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, ksh

i am trying something which make my work easier.So here i have a script which wl collect IPs from diff file. The problem is that output of awk is not storing/wrong syntax is wrong.i am using bash.

```
MGR${count_IP}=$(awk -F '[=;]' '{print $2}' "${MgrFile}")
echo "Test=MGR${count_IP}"

for (( count=1;count<=$Manager_Count;count++))
do
    MasterFile=/etc/ansible/tmp/tmp_list
    MgrFile=/etc/ansible/tmp/tmp_mgr$count
    echo "$count-$MgrFile"

    grep -r "Manager_$count" $MasterFile > "${MgrFile}"
    echo "Copy List of IP and name Info to temp file"

    echo "Get MGR$count IP"
    MGR${count_IP}=$(awk -F '[=;]' '{print $2}' "${MgrFile}")
    echo "MGR${count_IP}"
done
```

Issue Part

```
    echo "Get MGR$count IP"
    MGR${count_IP}=$(awk -F '[=;]' '{print $2}' "${MgrFile}")
    echo "MGR${count_IP}"
```

Log:

```
 1-/etc/ansible/tmp/tmp_mgr1
 Copy List Info to temp file
 Get MGR1 IP
 ./2.sh: line 47: MGR=172.16.16.11: command not found
 MGR
 2-/etc/ansible/tmp/tmp_mgr2
 Copy List Info to temp file
 Get MGR2 IP
 ./2.sh: line 47: MGR=172.16.16.14: command not found
 MGR
```

Comment: A shell is an environment from which to call tools. It is not a tool to manipulate text. If you'd like help doing whatever you are trying to do the right way, then post a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Not at all, string manipulation functionality is extremely useful and necessary in the context of manipulating files and processes and sequencing calls to tools which is what a shell is for. Where would we be if we couldn't do `cmd "$file" > "${file%.csv}.txt"`, etc.? Since there's so many ways with UNIX tools that you can produce the desired output from a given sample input, its very important to learn the right tools for each job rather than hammering in your nails with a screwdriver and driving your screws with a chisel.

Comment: @LarryMcQueary you might be interested in this answer written by the guy who discovered [the Shellshock bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) everyone was stunned by a couple of years ago: [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). Although the question was about loops, the answer also gives some insight into issues related to manipulating text with shell in general.

Answer (score -2):

This looks like a simple mix-up:

- your variable is called `$count` until the first line of the issue part
- after that it is called `$count_IP`

So

```
echo "Get MGR$count IP"
eval "MGR$count=\$(awk -F '[=;]' '{print \$2;}' '$MgrFile')"
echo "MGR${count}"
```

should work

Comment: There's a `$count_IP` on the first line of the script though, but definitely some kind of mixup.

Comment: I can say its partial as echo "MGR${count}" does not carry the output of awk.

Comment: Issue Pats description is as follows.Here with  echo "Get MGR$count IP" i am getting "Get MGR1 IP". In 2nd line awk will return me the ip which i am trying to store in a new variable with count variable.variable name will be like MGR1_IP.By 3rd line i am expecting MGR1_IP=10.10.10.10

Comment: works with this.Donot know why it need something after MGR$count  in 2nd line echo "Get MGR$count IP"
eval "MGR$count_IP=\$(awk -F '[=;]' '{print \$2;}' '$MgrFile')"
echo "$MGR$count_IP